# AuthenticateResult.Principal is null when trying to authenticate with Google

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, blazor, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to allow users to log in with their Google account on my ASP.NET Core Blazor app. Whenever I go to my app/login/google-login, everything works as expected. I get redirected to google's login page and I get to choose an account to log in with. After choosing my account, it takes a few seconds to load and then visual studio 2019 tells me this:

`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticateResult.Principal.get returned null.`

at this block of code:

```
var claims = response.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.Select(claim => new
                    {
                        claim.Issuer,
                        claim.OriginalIssuer,
                        claim.Type,
                        claim.Value
                    });
```

Some debugging has revealed the following:
`{"succeeded":false,"ticket":null,"principal":null,"properties":null,"failure":null,"none":true}`

This is the response I get from Google's API formatted as JSON. Basically it tells me that the principal is null, which I could have guessed, but the rest is also null. What's going on here? Could this simply be an issue with my scopes on Google's end? I have reasons to believe this isn't the problem though since my app should be able to work with any API response without crashing, right?

Here's my LoginController.cs class:

```
[AllowAnonymous, Route("login")]
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        [Route("google-login")]
        public IActionResult GoogleLogin()
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse") };
            return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        [Route("google-response")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
         {
            var response = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var claims = response.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.Select(claim => new
                {
                    claim.Issuer,
                    claim.OriginalIssuer,
                    claim.Type,
                    claim.Value
                });

            return Json(claims);
        }
    }
```

Here's my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            //services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context")));
            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<IReservationService, ReservationService>();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/login/google-login";
            })
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Google:ClientID"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();

                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
```

If you need any additional info or code, I'll be happy to provide that ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

This line, that is arguably a fairly big part of my project, was preventing communication with Google for who knows what reason.

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>();
```

I now basically just went on without UserManager and RoleManager and just wrote manual methods for accessing AspNetUsers etc.

Probably not a real solution but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Come here late, but recently meet the same error. And i have this log:

```
The cookie 'idsrv.external' has set 'SameSite=None' and must also set 'Secure'.
```

I figure out that if cookie has set SameSite=None, the callback Url must be https to receive the Cookie from Google. Because your app don't have the Cookie, so it cannot Authorize by following line:

```
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse") };
```

Change developer Url to https will resolve this.
Example: https://localhost:5000